# couldn't decode Object with field Type Map[String, String] using circe

Tags: json, scala, scala-cats, circe

I have an case class which contains field of type `Map[String, String]`

The complete class definition is -

`case class MyConfig(version: Int, pairs: Map[String, String])`.

The json I'm trying to decode is -

```
{  
   "version":1,
   "pairs":[  
      {  
         "key1":"value1",
         "key2":"value2"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I try to decode the string into MyConfig object `println(decode[MyConfig](jsonStr))` I get the below error -

`Left(DecodingFailure([K, V]Map[K, V], List(DownField(pairs))))`.

The complete code is -

```
case class MyConfig(version: Int, pairs: Map[String, String])

  import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.syntax._

  val jsonStr = """    {
                  |       "version":1,
                  |       "pairs":[
                  |          {
                  |             "key1":"value1",
                  |             "key2":"value2"
                  |          }
                  |       ]
                  |    }  """.stripMargin

  println(jsonStr)

  println(decode[MyConfig](jsonStr))
```

I'm able to decode Map json object as demonstrated [here](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html#custom-key-types) but not object with map field.

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the generically derived decoder will try to parse the `"pairs"` value as a `Map[String, String]`, which means it will look for a JSON object, while what you have is a JSON array of objects.

If you're stuck with that `MyConfig` definition and input that's shaped like that, you're probably best off writing your own decoder instead of deriving one with `io.circe.generic.auto`. This is pretty straightforward with `forProductN`:

```
case class MyConfig(version: Int, pairs: Map[String, String])

import io.circe.Decoder

implicit val decodeMyConfig: Decoder[MyConfig] =
  Decoder.forProduct2[MyConfig, Int, List[Map[String, String]]](
    "version",
    "pairs"
  ) {
    case (v, ps) => MyConfig(v, ps.flatten.toMap)
  }
```

And then, assuming you've defined `jsonStr` as above:

```
scala> import io.circe.parser.decode
import io.circe.parser.decode

scala> decode[MyConfig](jsonStr)
res0: Either[io.circe.Error,MyConfig] = Right(MyConfig(1,Map(key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2)))
```

Alternatively you could either change `MyConfig` so that the `pairs` member is a `List[Map[String, String]]`, or you could change the JSON schema (or whatever code is generating it) to omit the JSON array layer.